# Process 'command '/home/bgn-dev/Android/Sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, android-xml, androidx

After migrating my project to Android X, there was an error like in the title. gradle.app is as follows. I would be very happy if you could help. Thank you.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.burakgon.hyperaudio"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1005
        versionName "1005d"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            def version = variant.versionName
            outputFileName = "hyperaudio-${version}.apk"
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
ext {
    supportLibVersion = '28.0.0'  // variable that can be referenced to keep support libs consistent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the google() repo in the top level gradle file and also it should be before jcenter():

```
 buildscript {
      repositories {
              google()
              jcenter()
          }


    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
       }
    }

    allprojects {
         repositories {
                  google()
                 jcenter()
      }
    }
```